# 11 x [27] = 297 & 792 ÷ 11 = [72] ...why is that?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Another example of a reversed factor giving you a reversed multiple is

11 x [53] = 583 & 385 ÷ 11 = [35]

Is that pattern unique to the number 11 ~ google wouldn't say :(

& what is the name of that particular pattern (please don't refer to the "divisibilty rule") ?

The above "reversible factor / reverse multiple" pattern occurs quite often in the 11-times-table...

1 to 18, 20 to 27, 30 to 36, 40 to 45, 50 to 56, 60 to 63, 70 to 72, 80 to 81, & 90 x 11 can all be reversed to give the reverse of the original factor...

so, if you reverse the answer to 61x11 and divide it by 11 you will get 16, and so on.

No doubt, the fact that 11 is a double digit has something / everything to do with it, but what? google wouldn't tell me that either :(

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you have a 2-digit number $x = 10a + b$ (you write $x$ as $ab$) then
$$
11x = 110a + 11b = 100a + 10(a+b) + b,
$$
which means the left digit goes to the left, right digit goes to the right and in the middle you insert their sum.

This also explains the exceptions. To handle overflow, when $a+b>10$, you carry the one to the left digit. In other words, $23 \times 11$ means $2$ then $2+3=5$ then $3$, so a total of $253$, but $48 \times 11$ means $4$ then $4+8=12$ so write $2$ and carry the one to make left digit $4+1=5$ and finish with $8$ to get $528$...

This is one of the famous easy-to-remember rules of multiplication by $11$, used for example, by Trakhtenberg in his arithmetic (with slight modification works for multi-digit numbers as well).